# how to remove items from DOM and XPath in my browser?

Tags: html, dom, xpath, element, removechild

I hope somebody can help. I'm trying to remove items from ebay listings with the Firefox addon RIP (remove it permanently) which uses XPath and removes selected paths. As a side note: the addon is quite old and so it only works with old versions of Firefox. But I think the addon itself is not really relevant for the solution since I guess it's an XPath problem that needs to be solved.

So for example, if I want to remove every item on this ebay listing:

[ebay listing](https://www.ebay.de/sch/625/i.html?_udhi=400&LH_Auction=1&_fpos=&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=1&_dmd=1&_pgn=1&_skc=0)

that contains the keyword "Agfa" I try this (after checking the source code of the webpage):

```
//li[@class='s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom']/img[contains(@alt,'Agfa')]
```

I have also tried different approaches but to no avail. The items would not get removed. Note that the ebay listings are updated all the time, so you will need to try with other keywords that are currently in the listing.

does anybody have a clue how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I sucessfully done to remove Agfa item in dev tools of your browser:

```
$x('//li[@data-viewport][contains(., "AGFA")]')[0].remove()
```

For multiples items:

```
$x('//li[@data-viewport][contains(., "AGFA")]').filter(elt => elt.remove())
```

If you just need the XPath to feed `RIP` :

```
'//li[@data-viewport][contains(., "AGFA")]'
```

Comment: Hi Gilles, thank you for your reply. I am not familiar with dev tools, is it buillt into Firefox and how do I use it?

Comment: Just type my last snippet in console tab of firefox dev tools : ctrl+shift+c

Comment: ok, that worked, great :-) Can there also be multiple lines of this code snippet for multiple keywords and most importantly can a batch of such commands be saved and used permanently with the listings? I also have items that must only be removed if a keyword is present but another keyword is not, like for example: "only remove item if keyword "AGFA" is present but the keyword "Canon" is not. Perhaps you can indicate how to do this as well?

Comment: oh, I see you have added the command for RIP, I'll check this now, thank you!

Comment: You can create a userscript with Tampermonkey if RIP is not what you expect. https://www.tampermonkey.net/

Comment: awesome, yes it does work! With RIP I'm familiar and how to use a batch of commands and different keywords. Thank you! I'll now mark the question as answererd. Your answer will probably help others as well :-)